# Explanation of AES/CFB code part

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need some help from someone to explain to me how a specific part of the following code works and the use of it. The code is an implementation of AES/CFB mode with client and server.
The code can be found on [this](http://malhar2010.blogspot.se/2011/05/using-aes-cfb-encryption-in-java-with.html) link.

The part that I do not understand is:

```
if(ivector==null)  
    {  
     iv = null;  
    }  
  else  
    {  
   iv = new byte[ivector.length];  
   for(int i=0;i<ivector.length;i++)  
      {  
    iv[i]=ivector[i];  
      }  
    }
```

1. What does it do?
2. Why is this needed?
3. Can I implement this inside the server.java respective client.java?

Comment: No offence, but my #infosec heart skips a few beats when I see questions like this. Given that your linked "source" material is authored in Java, the answer to question #3 is likely, yes. That you ask #1 and #2 compels me to implore you to study [AES symmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

Answer (score 2):

1. This code copies an array (in an unnecessarily complicated and verbose way).
2. If you want to ensure that other code with a reference to an array doesn't modify the content of the array, it can be useful to make a private copy of the array.
3. This question doesn't make sense.

Don't use the linked code as an example. It doesn't work correctly, and even if it did, it's a horrible implementation.

Comment: You just beat me. Wonder why I ever looked that that crap though. `iv = null`... sigh.

Comment: Oh bless you both @erickson and Maaren. I did harbor thoughts of responding in a far more indelicate manner.